# Dynamic Drowpdown on Select2 livewire laravel 8

Tags: jquery-select2, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I build a dynamic dropdown in select option but when i implement a select2 package it not work. Here is my code. The value of type not passing to the court select.

here is my Blade.php

```
{{$selectedType}}
<div class="row g-3 mb-3">
<div class="col-md">
  <div class="form-floating" wire:ignore>
    <select class="form-select" id="type" wire:model="selectedType" required>
        <option value="">Select Court Type</option>
        @foreach($types as $type)
        <option value="{{$type->id}}">{{$type->court_type_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <label for="floatingInputGrid">Type</label>
  </div>
</div>

@if (!is_null($courts))
<div class="col-md">
  <div class="form-floating" wire:ignore>
    <select class="form-select" wire:model="selectedCourt" required>
        <option value="">Select Court Location</option>
        @foreach($courts as $court)
        <option value="{{$court->id}}">{{$court->court_name}}, {{$court->province}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <label for="floatingInputGrid">Court Location</label>
  </div>
</div>
@endif

</div>
```

The livewire components works perfectly but in select2 it not work

```
public function render()
{
    $types = Type::All();
    $periods = Period::All();
    return view('livewire.collection.add', compact('types', 'periods'));
}

public function updatedSelectedType($court_id)
{
    $this->courts = Court::where('court_type', $court_id)->orderBy('court_name')->get();
}

public function updatedSelectedCourt($clerk_id)
{
    $this->clerks = Clerk::where('court', $clerk_id)->get();
}
```

Select2

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.form-select').select2();
        $('#type').on('change', function (e) {
            var data = $('#type').select2("val");
            @this.set('selectedType', data);
        });
        
        $('#court').on('change', function (e) {
            var data = $('#court').select2("val");
            @this.set('selectedCourt', data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Nothing happen when clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve select2 element in Livewire like this.

```
<div class="form-floating">
    <select class="form-select" wire:model="selectedCourt">
        <option value="">Select Court Location</option>
        @foreach($courts as $court)
        <option value="{{$court->id}}">{{$court->court_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <label for="floatingInputGrid">Court Location</label>
</div>

//

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     window.initSelectDrop=()=>{
       $('.form-select').select2({
          placeholder: '{{ __('locale.Select') }}',
           allowClear: true
       });
       initSelectDrop();
       $('.form-select').on('change', function (e) {
          livewire.emit('selectedItemCourt', e.target.value)
       });
       window.livewire.on('select2',()=>{
           initSelectDrop();
       });

  });
</script>
```

in component

```
public function hydrate()
{
   $this->emit('select2');
}

public $listeners = ['selectedItemCourt'];

//.....

public function selectedItemCourt($value)
{
   dd($value);
   $this->selectedCourt = $value;
}
```

Comment: not working select2 is back on default select

Comment: when the value court not null and show the court dropdown become default select2. Please see edited pic at the top

Comment: i added wire:ignore if i remove it the select 2 is not working

Comment: using my code, change or add a class to select element like select2 and get in script this element by this class name, diff to other in the blade. That code must work